# Why does libstdc++ implement both <L,R> and <LR> overloads for binary operators on iterators?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator, libstdc++

In *libstdc++3*, in the header *bits/stl_iterator.h* (GCC 10 source [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_iterator.h;h=2259f7c8393fa6b62bc310af57a4252a8f946386;hb=HEAD#l1113)), every binary operator for `__normal_iterator` has two overloads defined (here is `==` for example):

```
  template<typename _IteratorL, typename _IteratorR, typename _Container>
    _GLIBCXX20_CONSTEXPR
    inline bool
    operator==(const __normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>& __lhs,
           const __normal_iterator<_IteratorR, _Container>& __rhs)
    _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
    { return __lhs.base() == __rhs.base(); }

  template<typename _Iterator, typename _Container>
    _GLIBCXX20_CONSTEXPR
    inline bool
    operator==(const __normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>& __lhs,
           const __normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>& __rhs)
    _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
    { return __lhs.base() == __rhs.base(); }
```

Where `.base()` returns a pointer to an array element in this case. This is done throughout the library for other iterator types as well. According to comments and changelogs scattered throughout, it's done to support interoperability between `iterator`s and `const_iterator`s.

My question is, why are both the the `<_IteratorL, _IteratorR, _Container>` and `<_Iterator, _Container>` overloads defined for all of them? That is, why is `<_Iterator, _Container>` necessary? Wouldn't the former cover every case? What would break if the latter was removed?

GCC's *libstdc++* implementation has a lot of street cred, so I'm sure there's a good, possibly subtle reason, but I can't figure out what it could be.

I ask because I'm currently working out some kinks in my own custom iterator implementations and looking at the STL as a model.

Comment: The second overload allows an implicit conversion... the first one could fail that conversion (if it's a user-defined one) due to deduction failure.

Comment: @dyp I think I understand (maybe? is it for the same reason as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65401573/why-is-implicit-conversion-not-applied-to-templated-function-parameter?noredirect=1&lq=1)?) except I'm having trouble constructing a failure case (I was hoping [this](https://ideone.com/SEyJqU) wouldn't compile... but it does and I can't think of anything else to try).

Comment: ([My second attempt](https://ideone.com/uCQCjW) also fails to fail.)

Comment: Looks like I was mistaken: https://godbolt.org/z/9fGvja -- I thought this would work (deduction would fail but the overload still be viable). Now I'm confused :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment above that complains about [`std::rel_ops`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/rel_ops/operator_cmp), which provide a `template<class T> bool operator!=(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)`.

Reducing `__normal_iterator` to it's bare essentials to show the problem, we get this:

```cpp
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct normal_iterator {
    T m_base;

    const T& base() const { return m_base; }
};

// (1)
template<typename IteratorL, typename IteratorR>
bool operator!=(const normal_iterator<IteratorL>& lhs, const normal_iterator<IteratorR>& rhs) {
    return lhs.base() != rhs.base();
}

// (2)
template<typename Iterator>
bool operator!=(const normal_iterator<Iterator>& lhs, const normal_iterator<Iterator>& rhs) {
    return lhs.base() != rhs.base();
}

int main() {
    using namespace std::rel_ops;
    // Your container's `const_iterator` is `const int*`, and `iterator` is `int*`
    normal_iterator<const int*> a{nullptr};
    normal_iterator<int*> b{nullptr};
    a != b;  // Uses (1) to compare const_iterator and iterator

    a != a;  // Uses (2) to compare two iterators
}
```

Without the second overload, this would not compile since there are two viable functions to call:

```cpp
std::rel_ops::operator!=<normal_iterator<int*>>(const normal_iterator<int*>&, const normal_iterator<int*>&)

operator!=<int*, int*>(const normal_iterator<int*>&, const normal_iterator<int*>&)
```

And neither is more specialiased than the other (it is ambiguous)

---

For `std::rel_ops` specifically, there is no reason for the extra `==` overload, but nothing is stopping a user from writing a similar `template<typename T> bool operator==(const T&, const T&)` in some other namespace.

Comment: Ohhh; I was wondering what that comment was about ([if anybody is curious](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_iterator.h;h=2259f7c8393fa6b62bc310af57a4252a8f946386;hb=HEAD#l1088)). Ok, just to make sure I understand; it's not done because it's technically necessary on its own, it's done defensively as preemptive protection against ambiguity if an equally specialized option is defined somewhere else, so that it doesn't interfere. Correct? This also explains why I've been having a hard time constructing a failure case.

Comment: @JasonC The (19 year old) commit that introduces it (https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commitdiff;h=f1e888aea0089c38d73de22e2ad79e40d3e65da8) seems to be a bugfix for https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=3628. So yes, this doesn't seem completely necessary, and a conformant standard library is allowed to have this ambiguity with `using namespace std::rel_ops` (You could have a non-template `bool operator==(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator) { return false; }` in a namespace. That does not make `std::vector<int>::iterator` no longer an iterator)